# Single value "db_query": How to SELECT value that related to the node

Tags: 7, rules, database

From [this page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7), if what we need is SELECT single value, we can use `fetchField` method like below:

```
$nbr_records = db_query("SELECT count(nid) FROM {joke}")->fetchField();
```

I've created single value `Integer` field type with machine name `field_subscription_period` attached to node type `yearly_rent`.

I'm using this in Rules Action.

I've tested many db_query example with no luck.

Below is what I'm using, which it will get value of `entity_id` `2`:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT field_subscription_period_value FROM {field_data_field_subscription_period} WHERE entity_id = 2")->fetchField();
```

Above query will get value of `entity_id` `2`... but I want to SELECT `field_subscription_period` value that related to the node. So, how to get value that related to the node?

**-newly added-**

I still don't understand how to use `$node = node_load($nid);`. Lets say I want to use the value as variable to be calculated in date field.

I've tried below with no luck:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$values = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_subscription_period');
$newdate = strtotime("+$values year","$value");
return $newdate;
```

..and also I got error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: nid in eval() (line 1 of /var/www/testd7/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(146) : eval()'d code).
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7539 of /var/www/testd7/includes/common.inc).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use direct queries to the database tables used for fields, for the simple fact the fields could not use database tables to store their value; this is what happens by default, but if a different storage implementation is exposed by a module, the information will be saved in another place. That is actually what happens with the [Mongodb](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb) module.

If you know the node ID, and you want to get the value of a field associated to it, you can use the following code.

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$values = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_subscription_period');
```

`$values` is an array whose structure depends from the field. It contains at least an item, but the exact number depends from how many values the field can have. (It is normally set in the setting page for the field.)
To see the structure of that array, you should install the Devel module, and use test code similar to the following one.

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$values = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_subscription_period');
dsm($values);
```

For example, the first screenshot shows the structure used for a node body, while the second one shows the structure used for an image field.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

If you need to find all the nodes of a specific content type, and filter out the list basing on the value set for a field, you should use the [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class, as in the following code.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'yearly_rent')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_subscription_period', 'value', $minimum_value, '>')
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.

$result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
}
```

`addMetaData('account', user_load(1))` is necessary because the `EntityFieldQuery` class respects the access permission associated with fields; if the current user doesn't have access to the field, `fieldCondition()` would fail.
Once you have the node object, you can use [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7). If you want to obtain a value to render, you should call [field_view_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7).

Comment: Still not works, I dont understand how to use it. The question has been updated above

Comment: But sadly, it looks impossible to use `nid` in Rules if I choose `Set a data value` action.